# Alter Variables in List with purrr

Tags: r, purrr

I have three datasets `a`, `b`, `c` with identical variable names. I want to check whether these variables contain missing/invalid values.

I have a checking function `check_variables()` that checks missing or invalid values (for example the function could just be  `is.na`).

While I could apply my checking function `check_variables()` explicitly to each of these datasets, like:

```r
check.output = list(
    a = check_variables(a),
    b = check_variables(b),
    c = check_variables(c)
)
```

purrr offers a nice all-in-one-step solution for this problem:

```r
list(a,b,c) %>%
    map(~ .x %>% check_variables())
```

But this step only maps `check_variables()` to elements of datasets in the list. Instead, I want function `check_variables()` map to each dataset. Is there a way to effectively map functions to the datasets in the list instead of the elements within each dataset?

Comment: R (and most other functional languages) don't really work like this. It would be best to keep related data.frames in the list all the time rather than trying to work with three different variables. Functions should always return new objects rather than replacing existing objects. It's much safer to work with data that way.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] including sample data sets `a`, `b`, `c`, a sample implementation of  `check_variables()`. and your expected output. As it is currently written, the question is hard for me to understand what you are after. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the independent variables you can pass a list of variable names to edit then use `get` and `assign` to access and modify them.

```r
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)

a = list(var = 1)
b = list(var = 2)
c = list(var = 3)

# get the current environment. alternative is to use functions like 
# parent.frame from within the loop but that can get confusing
e = environment()

c('a','b','c') %>% 
    map(function(x){
        ls = get(x,envir = e)
        # whatever modification you want to make on the list
        ls$var = ls$var+1
        assign(x,ls,envir = e)
    })
```

Note in real life, as @MrFlick stated, you probably don't want to do this. Keep a, b, c in a single list and your downstream analysis will be easier since I assume they will have to be processes through the same pipeline. map will happily return your modified list that you can either use to overwrite the original list or assign to a new variable. Alternatively, use a `for` loop over list indexes to modify the original list on the go or fill a pre-allocated new variable.

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is to apply `check_variables()` which takes in a dataset (table) and returns a single `TRUE` or `FALSE`, then the issue might be related to the usage of vectorized functions.

R and packages of R have many vectorized functions, such as `is.na`, which means when applying these function on to a list `c(1, NA, 2)` or dataframe, the function will be applied on to each elements of the list, resulting `FALSE TRUE FALSE` instead of `TRUE` (any element `is.na`) or `FALSE` (all element `is.na`).

When `check_variable()` function is composed by these vectorized functions, we will need to "aggregate" the vectorized functions use functions like `all`, `any`. Further more we will need to control the scope of aggregation in order to control whether the `check_variables()` function is to be applied on elements, variables (columns), or the entire table(dataframe):

```r
require(tidyverse) # in production code, import only `dplyr` and `tidyr`
require(purrr)

a = data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y =c(3,NA,5))
b = data.frame(x = c(1,NA,3), y =c(3,4,5))
c = data.frame(x = c(1,NA,3), y =c(3,NA,4))

# apply `check.func` on varaibles(columns)
# aggregation has to be limited within scope of each varaible (column)
# `dplyr::summarize_all` happens to functioning like this
check.vars = function(list.tbls, check.func) list.tbls %>% map(~ .x %>% summarize_all(check.func) )

# apply `check.func` on the entire table
# as long as `check.func` takes a table and returns a single value
# we can directly apply this function
check.tbls = function(list.tbls, check.func) list.tbls %>% map(~ check.func(.x))


## Some sample functions

# check if all elements under the scope, has no NA
# take in either a vector or a table, return a boolean
has.no.na = . %>% is.na %>% any %>% `!`

# check if all elements under the scope is less than 5, NAs are counted as False
# take in either a vector or a table, return a boolean
has.no.na = . %>% is.na %>% any %>% `!` 
is.lt.5  = . %>% `<`(5) %>% all %>% replace_na(F)

# check if all elements under the scope is less than 5, NAs are ignored, all NA means TRUE
# take in either a vector or a table, return a boolean
is.lt.5.rm.na  = . %>% `<`(5) %>% all(na.rm=T)


## Use of sample functions to check variables within each dataset
list(a,b,c) %>% check.vars(has.no.na)
list(a,b,c) %>% check.vars(is.lt.5)

## Use of sample functions to check each dataset
list(a,b,c) %>% check.tbls(has.no.na)
list(a,b,c) %>% check.tbls(is.lt.5)
list(a,b,c) %>% check.tbls(is.lt.5.rm.na)
```